# @IBAction func is not running on tap with both UILabel and UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

This is my ViewController:

```
import UIKit
var optionChoice: Int = 0

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var storyLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionTwo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionThree: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionFour: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func optionPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        optionChoice = sender.tag
        print(optionChoice)
    }
```

I've keep creating an @IBAction func for a tap to set optionChoice = sender.tag, but no results. It won't print optionChoice either from within the IBAction function, so it shows it is not running.

When I redid this with UIButtons instead of labels, the same results happened, except I could see that the buttons were successfully being pressed from the animation.

When I removed `optionChoice = sender.tag` and replaced it with an if/else statement

```
if sender.tag == 1 {
optionChoice = 1 }
```

I still have the same issue - @IBAction still does not run.

Note: `override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()` is still present in my code at the bottom by default, I didn't include it in the snippet to save space.

I checked out other questions and I don't think this is a duplicate because other questions had multiple view controllers and were resolving the function to other screens, or something along these lines. I have a simple single test screen with only the objects outlined.

Any help would be most appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the label, there's no surprise, since by default labels are not tappable.

With the button, it's tappable, but nothing will happen unless you configure an *action in the storyboard* from the button's Touch Up Inside control event to the `optionPressed` method in the view controller.

Comment: I forgot to configure an action in the storyboard with Touch Up Inside to the optionPressed method - thank you!